# Count multiple occurrences of some text for each file under a directory

Tags: bash, grep, wc

I am trying to count multiple occurrences of some text for each file under a directory.  The following script is close to what I want but it does not count multiple occurrences on the same line:

```
grep -rc 'blah' /some/path --include \*.txt
```

For example given two files:

```
foo.txt
blah, hey blah
some more text

bar.txt
something blah
```

The above script produces:

```
foo.txt:1
bar.txt:1
```

But the output I am looking for is*:

```
foo.txt:2
bar.txt:1
```

I know that the total number of occurrences can be found in one file using grep and then piping the results to word count:

```
grep -oh 'blah' foo.txt|wc -l
```

How to do this for multiple files to achieve the output as in my example* above?

**Update**

The best solution I could come up with is as follows:

```
find /some/path -name '*.txt'|awk '{print "echo -n '\''" 
    $0 "\: '\'' && grep -oh '\''blah'\'' " $0 "|wc -l"}'|bash
```

Answer (score 2):

grep -o prints each match on new line - then count em up

```
dir=$1
grep -Hor --include '*.txt' 'blah' $dir|
uniq -c|
# output after uniq
#      3 dir/f0.txt:blah
#      2 dir/f1.txt:blah
awk '{file=gensub(/^.+\/|:.+/, "", "g", $2); print file ":" $1}'
```